Postres docker разрешить подключение только с одного хоста
Кто сможет подсказать, установил контейнер с postgres. По умолчанию разрешены все хосты к подключению. Пытаюсь настроить, чтобы можно было подключаться только с одного, но не получается. Подскажите как исправить? pg_hda.conf прикладываю ниже.
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             172.24.0.6/32           scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256

